# How to run awk in gnuplot scripts via msysgit bash

Tags: windows, awk, gnuplot, msysgit, git-bash

My gnuplot scripts use `awk` to preprocess some data. Everything works fine in Linux.
But I also like to run these scripts in Windows. Most of the time I use the **Git Bash** (msysgit) for my command line work in Windows. This saves me from maintaining windows batch files in addition to my shell scripts.

The problem is that Git Bash does not provide a `gnuplot` command, although it does provide `awk`. I manually installed Gnuplot (MinGW) and added it's bin dir to the `%PATH%`.

Now I can run `gnuplot` from the Git Bash. But since it is a "Windows app" it does not recognize the tools/binaries provided by the MSYS Git, such as `awk`. I think I could add Git's MSYS `bin` dir to the `%PATH%`, but (as the Git installer tells you) this might interfere with some OS systems functions. I also do not want to install another MSYS. The Git version is just fine as it is for me.

Is there a better solution to get gnuplot running with my MSYS binaries (esp. `awk`).

Comment: This isn't an answer, but often you can replace simple `awk` scripts with `using` filters which would remove your dependence on an external tool.

Comment: In one of my plots I am adding up an arbitrary number of columns, i.e., column pairs, using `awk`. My log file looks like: `a b c d e f1 g1 f2 g2 f3 g3...`. I sum up the varying number of `f` and `g` columns. I think this is not possible via `using`. Anyway, that's worth another question I guess ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quite simply solution to my problem. One solution would be adding the full Git/bin to the `%PATH%` which I did not want to do (see above). But if you just need a few commands you can setup a simple non intrusive "mini" MSYS in one of your `bin` folders (those already in your `%PATH%`), or you create a new one and add that to the `%PATH%`.

**Setting up `awk` for my `gnuplot` scripts:**

1. Copy `gawk.exe` from the `Git/bin` to `%HOME%/bin/awk.exe`
2. Copy `msys-1.0.dll` from `Git/bin` to `%HOME%/bin`
3. Add `%HOME%/bin` to your `%PATH%` (if not already)

To test it, just open the command line and type `awk`. I can now double click my `plot.sh` script which is automatically run via Git's `bash`. The script calls the `gnuplot` Windows binary of, which you should also have on your `%PATH%`, and `gnuplot` finally (internally) calls `awk`.

Works like a charm!